# htaccess site ip redirect to www

Tags: .htaccess

I already have a few rules set up redirecting users, like none www to www.

but google is still indexing the site ip address i would like this to be redirect to www.and the same if a user tried it

dose any one know how to write this in the htaccess file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect any request where the host does not start with www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks i actually did it this way...' RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP.IP.IP.IP [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] '
but yours is more global